# How work with one array and two react native pickers

Tags: react-native

I want to use one data array for two of pickers. If one picker selected one option then I need to remove that option from other picker. I tried this from following code. I used array of length 2.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startTown: 'Start Point',
      endTown: 'End Point',
      townList: null,
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    firebase.database().ref('busRoutes').once("value",(snapshot)=>{
      this.setState({townList:snapshot.val()})
    })
  }

<Box dir="row">
    <Picker
      style={{flex: 1}}
      selectedValue={startTown}
      onValueChange={(value) => {
      this.setState({
         startTown: value,
      });
    }}>
    <Picker.Item value='Start Point' label='Start Point' />
    {townList && townList.map((element,index)=>{
         if(element===endTown) return;
         return(<Picker.Item value={element} label={element} />)
     })}
   </Picker>
   <Picker
       style={{flex: 1}}
       selectedValue={endTown}
       onValueChange={(value) => {
         this.setState({
            endTown: value,
         });
       }}>
    <Picker.Item value='End Point' label='End Point' />
    {townList && townList.map((element,index)=>{
        if(element===startTown) return; 
        return(<Picker.Item value={element} label={element} />)
     })}
   </Picker>
</Box>
```

But it gives error like this

> length=2;index=2

here is the link to image with error. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwJkJ.jpg
I can`t put it here as my reputations are not enough

Comment: you can clone first the array so that change in one can't affect the another. try to use enabled=false for the picker.Item instead of removing it.

Comment: @prabhat Unfortunately there is not `enabled` attribute in Picker.Item